# How can I get a list of all timezone IDs in Java 8?

Tags: java, java-8

In the `java.time` package I do not see a function to get a list of available timezone IDs. I am able to call the `getAvailableIDs()` in `java.util.TimeZone`library. However, I want to use Java 8 instead.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Why can't you use `java.util.TimeZone`? [It is available in Java 8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/TimeZone.html).

Comment: how about `Set<String> getAvailableZoneIds()` from `java.time.ZoneId`(since 1.8), see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html for reference

Comment: @Code-Apprentice The problem with java.util.TimeZone is that it doesn't filter deprecated 3 char timezones, such as BST, EST etc.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## `ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds()`

[`ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneId.html) exists in the [`java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) package.

[`ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html#getAvailableZoneIds--) ➙ [`Set<String>`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html)

> This set includes the string form of all available region-based IDs.
>   Offset-based zone IDs are not included in the returned set. The ID can
>   be passed to of(String) to create a ZoneId.
>
> The set of zone IDs can increase over time, although in a typical
>   application the set of IDs is fixed. Each call to this method is
>   thread-safe.